# Как перенести этот код jQuery на Vue и Axios

Tags: html, jquery, django, vue.js, axios

```
$(function (){
    $('#message').on('submit', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = new FormData($(this).get(0));
        console.log(form)
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type:"POST",
            data:form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data)
                var time = setInterval(function (){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/check/" + data["task_id"],
                        type:"GET",
                        success: function (data){
                            console.log(data)
                            if (data["status"] !== 'evaluation'){
                                clearInterval(time);
                                alert(data["status"])
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (){
                            console.log("BAD")
                        }
                })
            }, 1000)},
            error: function (){
                console.log("BAD")
            }
        })
    })

})
```

А вот html к которому это относится:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
    <h1 class="cover-heading center" align="center">Решение задач на код</h1>
    <form action="add_task/" method="post" id="message">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="codeeditor">Напишите метод суммирующий два числа a и b.</label>
        <textarea class="form-control border" rows="5" v-model="text" id="codeeditor"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="mt-3 btn-lg btn-secondary">
            Отправить
        </button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: ну, главное, что направление у вас правильное

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov направление то может быть и правильно, а вот действия в этом направлении нет =)

Comment: Интересный вопрос... Берёшь и переносишь!)